# How do I get to the final expression in T(n)

Tags: complexity-theory, discrete-mathematics

I've been reading about algorithmic complexity and I understand how to get to the formula below it:

[image: Resultant Formula]

but not like is that you get to this other formula after clearing the sum:

[image: Final]

Is that internal terms of the sum can be drawn outside and inside would be something like the infinite series (n*(n + 1))/2 .. but not like raising operations, I have doubts?

regards
cronos

Comment: The "trick" is to change the summation index.

Comment: I just did the math and the result you provided is wrong. The sum evaluates to `7n^2/2 - n/2 + 6`. Perhaps you misparenthesized?

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer, I should note two things.

- One, the sum doesn't evaluate to what you suggest. Perhaps you misparenthesized? Or made an error copying the experssion?
- And two, please provide some background, for example the algorithm the analysis of which yielded the expression for `T(n)`, so that the question will be at least tangentially relevant for the community.

First, let's simplify the expression for T(n), so that we have

```
T(n) = 3 + 3 + 3n + 7 * sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (n-i).
```

Noticing that the sum `n-i` for `i=1,2,...,n-1` is equivalent to the sum `1+2+...+n-i`, which, as we recall from high school, evaluates to `n(n-1)/2`, we get a new expressions for T(n):

```
T(n) = 3 + 3 + 3n + 7 * n*(n-1)/2
     = 6 + 3n + 7n(n-1)/2
     = 7n^2/2 - 7n/2 + 6n/2 + 6
     = 7^n2/2 - n/2 + 6
```